# How to rename generic XML elements using the elements of a header node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I get XML output from an online service that I can't manipulate. The `TableHeader` node contains the column names. Using XSLT 1.0, how can I rename the generic `Attribute` elements using the elements in `TableHeader`?

**XML input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SearchResults>
    <TableHeader>
        <ColumnName>Surname</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>FirstNames</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>Gender</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>Age</ColumnName>
    </TableHeader>
    <Object>
        <Attribute>Linder</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Sophie</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Female</Attribute>
        <Attribute/>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Attribute>?</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Thomas</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Male</Attribute>
        <Attribute>26</Attribute>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Attribute>Akona</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Lettie</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Female</Attribute>
        <Attribute>35</Attribute>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Attribute>Linder</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Fred</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Male</Attribute>
        <Attribute>38</Attribute>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Attribute>Akona</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Alicia</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Female</Attribute>
        <Attribute/>
    </Object>
</SearchResults>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SearchResults>
    <Object>
        <Surname>Linder</Surname>
        <FirstNames>Sophie</FirstNames>
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <Age/>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Surname>?</Surname>
        <FirstNames>Thomas</FirstNames>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <Age>26</Age>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Surname>Akona</Surname>
        <FirstNames>Lettie</FirstNames>
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <Age>35</Age>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Surname>Linder</Surname>
        <FirstNames>Fred</FirstNames>
        <Gender>Male</Gender>
        <Age>38</Age>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Surname>Akona</Surname>
        <FirstNames>Alicia</FirstNames>
        <Gender>Female</Gender>
        <Age/>
    </Object>
</SearchResults>
```

I am very new to XSLT, so I haven't progressed very far, but here is my current attempt. I thought I could maybe use `xsl:variable` to set the column names and then use those as element tags, but I am sure there must be a better way. Also, it should ideally work for a variable number of columns.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent ="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name ="column1" select ="(ColumnName)[1]" />
  <xsl:template match ="Object">
    <Object>
      <Surname>
        <xsl:value-of select="(Attribute)[1]"/>
      </Surname>
      <FirstName>
        <xsl:value-of select="(Attribute)[2]"/>
      </FirstName>
      <Gender>
        <xsl:value-of select="(Attribute)[3]"/>
      </Gender>
      <Age>
        <xsl:value-of select="(Attribute)[4]"/>
      </Age>
    </Object>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to group these using the Muenchian Method, but my understanding is that having more descriptive element names would make that a lot easier. If it could be achieved in one step without renaming, let me know in the comments and I'll post a separate question for that.

Comment: "*My ultimate goal is to be able to group these using the Muenchian Method, but my understanding is that having more descriptive element names would make that a lot easier.*" I am not at all convinced that it would. What do you want to group them by?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'd group them on Surname.

Comment: It can be done either way. It might be a bit simpler to code when the name is known, but you will have to make two passes in order to achieve that, so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, provided that the supplied column names are also valid XML element names:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="column-names" select="/SearchResults/TableHeader/ColumnName" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Attribute">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:element name="{$column-names[$i]}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TableHeader"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. I'll first try to group using the translation from this stylesheet. Once I understand that I'll see if I can cut it to one pass.